# problem with extracting a value with regular expression

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have a problem with extracting a value in a response in html with jmeter, I should extract the value with a regular expression, the value to extract is the following: nonce% 3DEMd70h7_AQzsXKQFANYigilzxkRnJCW_hW8O_7sVI9
i should extract everything except nonce% 3D
how to do?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to come up with a proper regular expression without seeing the full response, it could be something like

```
nonce% 3D(\w+)
```

[image]

where:

- `\w` stands for ["word"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp) (alpha-numeric, case insensitive, including underscores)
- `+` stands for "repetition"

If you have problems with coming up with a proper regular expression you might find [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) easier to use, it just fetches everything between left and right boundaries

[image]